# Porcelain.exec gave empty response

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am using ffprobe to get all parameters in RTSP stream like bitrate, fps etc.

I am using `Porcelain.exec` to execute command. Command works but `Porcelain` gave empty output but terminal shows command have parameters in output.

Here is code:

```
Porcelain.exec("ffprobe", ["rtsp://90.101.245.146:9201/h264/ch1/main/av_stream"]).out
```

It gave output empty string but terminal shows following command output.

```
Metadata:
   title: Media Presentation
Duration: N/A, start: 0.239978, bitrate: N/A
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25.25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Does this work: `Porcelain.exec("ffprobe", ["rtsp://90.101.245.146:9201/h264/ch1/main/av_stream"], [err: :out]).out`?

Comment: Yes, that's worked.

Answer (score 1):

`ffprobe` prints that data to stderr, and `Porcelain.exec` by default does not capture the output of `stderr`. With Porcelain's `Basic` driver you can redirect stderr to stdout and then read `.out`:

```
Porcelain.exec("ffprobe", ["rtsp://90.101.245.146:9201/h264/ch1/main/av_stream"], [err: :out]).out
```

With Porcelain's `Goon` driver, you can do more advanced stuff like redirecting to a stream or file. You can find out more about this in the [docs for Porcelain.exec/3](https://hexdocs.pm/porcelain/Porcelain.html#exec/3).